# testing simulating a keypress for an angular directive jasmine spec

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

How can I make it so that my simulated keypresses actually set the value of an input?

I am making a directive that monitors keypress events and modifies the value of the input based on the keypresses, I can't test this until I can actually see that simulated keypresses actually change the value of the text input.

```
describe('testingKeypress', function () {
  var context;

  beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
    context = this;

    this.compile           = $injector.get('$compile');
    this.rootScope         = $injector.get('$rootScope');
    this.document          = $injector.get('$document');
    this.scope             = this.rootScope.$new();

    this.pressKey = function (keyCode) {
      var e = $.Event('keypress');
      e.keyCode = keyCode;
      e.which = keyCode;
      context.el.find('input').trigger(e);
    };

    this.createElement = function () {
      context.el = angular.element('<form><input></form>');
      context.compile(context.el)(context.scope);
      context.scope.$digest();
    };
  }));

  afterEach(function() {
    this.scope.$destroy();
  });

  describe('making sure an input actually gets some text', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
      this.createElement();
      this.pressKey(65);
      this.pressKey(66);
      this.pressKey(67);
    });

    it('works', function () {
      expect(this.el.find('input').val()).toEqual('ABC');
    });
  });
});
```

> PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) making sure an input actually gets some text works FAILED
>   Expected '' to equal 'ABC'.